# echo Hello username after login

Tags: php, html, authentication

The first thing the user is asked is to login; if the login is successful the user is sent to the index.php if not; they're asked to re-enter their details.

I want the username to display on the index.php AFTER the user logs in;

so using an echo function in the index.php file to `GET` the username from the login

```
//check to see if they match
if($username==$dbusername&&$password==$password)
{
$_SESSION['username']=$username;
    echo "Welcome '.$username.'";
    header('Location: nindex.php');
    die(); 
}
else
echo "incorrect password";

}
else
    die("That user does not exist");
}
else
    die("please provide a  username and password");

?>
```

Comment: You cannot `echo` anything before the `header` line.

Comment: You have `$password==$password`. That will never be false. Besides, are you storing passwords in plain text?

Comment: Do you Really know that one can login to your system with only a correct username (without a password) because of your code?

Comment: i've only posted a snippet of the code, i've tested it; user needs both username and password

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
header("Refresh: 5; url=index.php");
echo "Welcome '" . $username . "'";
exit;#should be added so rest of page doesn't load.
```

OR

```
echo "Welcome '" . $username . "'";?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=index.php" />
<?php
exit;#should be added so rest of page doesn't load.
```

should tell them `Welcome 'username'` then redirect to your page after 5 seconds, you can change 5 to any number you think is long enough. It might be advisable to use the meta since the header might give you an error/warning.

**EDIT:**

It looks like you want to print `Welcome 'username'` on the index.php page you can do and and sure you have `session_start()` at the top of each page.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo "Welcome '{$_SESSION['username']}'";
}
```

and remove `echo "Welcome '.$username.'";` from your login page. If you want it display once I can modify my answer if you want.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' on line 4

Comment: @SH sorry add another `)` before `{` on the if isset

Comment: its displaying on the top of the page which is affecting the CSS. How could i get the username to display in the left menu?

Comment: @SH move the if(isset to your left menu in your html and make sure you have enclose php tags around it like so `<?php if(isset... ?>' and keep the session_start on the first line of your script

Answer (score 3):

You cant echo any output before calling 'header', otherwise you will get that error.

The echo command needs to be done in the called page nindex.php

Comment: yes, how to i echo command in the index.php page?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php


  if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {

      if($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword) {

            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("Location: index.php?id=$username");
            die();
      }else {
        echo 'incorrect username/password combination';
      }
  }else {
  echo 'Username and Password NOT FOUND! ';  
  }
```

In **index.php**  put

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
echo 'Welcome '.$_GET['id'];
}else {
echo '(write) a 404 page';

}
```

Comment: i need to do this in the index.php not the login.php

Comment: You can do this in index.php, just change where it says index.php to login.php It is very simple

Comment: @SH I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: edited the question, please let me know if this is more clear

Comment: So, this script will be in login.php, so once you log in, you want the page to take you, to index.php and show you your name?

Comment: yes i simply want the user to login, once they login they will be directed to the index.php and i want it to show their login username

Comment: @SH Copy and Paste it, I have tested it. And tell me, if you get error

Comment: almost forgot, to put something on the index page